# Iterator of repeated words in a file

Tags: scala, iterator

Suppose, I'm writing a function to find "repeated words" in a text file. For example, in `aaa aaa bb cc cc bb dd` repeated words are `aaa` and `cc` but not `bb`, because two `bb` instances don't appear next to each other.

The function receives an iterator and returns iterator like that:

```
def foo(in: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = ???

foo(Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb")) // Iterator("aaa", "cc")
foo(Iterator("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "b"))         // Iterator("a")
```

How would you write `foo` ? Note that the input is huge and all words do not fit in memory (but the number of repeated words is relatively small).

P.S. I would like also to enhance `foo` later to return also positions of the repeated words, the number of repetitions, etc.

Comment: What if you have 3 or more repetitions? What is the desired output?

Comment: `aaa aaa aaa bb bb cc dd cc dd` -> `aaa bb`

Comment: Do you have limits on solution? E.g., readability, height speed or low memory usage? In any case it should be dictionary (like `Map`).

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Thanks, but I assume the input is huge and does not fit in memory. So `toMap` is probably not feasible.

Comment: I will add this limitation to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

OK then. Let specify bit what you want:

```
 input       | expected    
             |             
 a           |             
 aa          | a           
 abc         |             
 aabc        | a           
 aaabbbbbbc  | ab          
 aabaa       | aa          
 aabbaa      | aba         
 aabaa       | aa
```

Is it true? If so this is working solution. Not sure about performance but at least it is lazy (don't load everything into memory).

```scala
//assume we have no nulls in iterator.
def foo[T >: Null](it:Iterator[T]) = {
  (Iterator(null) ++ it).sliding(3,1).collect {
    case x @ Seq(a,b,c) if b == c && a != b => c
  }
}
```

We need this ugly `Iterator(null) ++` because we are looking for 3 elements and we need a way to see if first two are the same.

This is pure implementation and it has some advantages over imperative one (eg. in other answers). Most important one is that it is lazy:

```scala
//infinite iterator!!!
val it = Iterator.iterate('a')(s => (s + (if(Random.nextBoolean) 1 else 0)).toChar)
//it'll take only as much as needs to take this 10 items.
//should not blow up
foo(it).take(10)
//imperative implementation will blow up in such situation.
fooImp(it).take(10)
```

here are all implementations from this and other posts seen in this topic:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/w5yozTA/15

**WITH INDEXES AND POSITIONS**

In comment you have asked if it would be easy to add the number of repeated words and their indices. I thought about it for a while and i've made something like this. Not sure if it has great performance but it should be lazy (eg. should work for big files).

```
/** returns Iterator that replace consecutive items with (item, index, count). 
It contains all items from orginal iterator.  */
def pack[T >: Null](it:Iterator[T]) = {
  //Two nulls, each for one sliding(...) 
  (Iterator(null:T) ++ it ++ Iterator(null:T))
  .sliding(2,1).zipWithIndex
  //skip same items
  .filter { case (x, _) => x(0) != x(1) }
  //calculate how many items was skipped
  .sliding(2,1).collect {
    case Seq((a, idx1), (b, idx2)) => (a(1), idx1 ,idx2-idx1)  
  }
}

def foo[T >: Null](it:Iterator[T]) = pack(it).filter(_._3 > 1)
```

**OLD ANSWER (BEFORE UPDATE QUESTION)**

Another (simpler) solution could be something like this:

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable._

//Create new iterator each time we'll print it.
def it = Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd", "dd", "ee",  "ee", "ee", "ee", "ee", "aaa", "aaa", "ff", "ff", "zz", "gg", "aaa", "aaa")

//yep... this is whole implementation :)
def foo(it:Iterator[String]) = it.sliding(2,1).collect { case Seq(a,b) if a == b => a } 


println(foo(it).toList) //dont care about duplication
//List(aaa, cc, dd, ee, ee, ee, ff)

println(foo(it).toSet) //throw away duplicats but don't keeps order
//Set(cc, aaa, ee, ff, dd)

println(foo(it).to[ListSet]) //throw away duplicats and keeps order
//ListSet(aaa, cc, dd, ee, ff)

//oh... and keep result longer than 5 items while testing. 
//Scala collections (eg: Sets) behaves bit diffrently up to this limit (they keeps order)
//just test with bit bigger Sequences :)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/w5yozTA/1

(if answer is helpful up-vote please)

Comment: Thanks but `foo(Iterator("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "b")).toList` returns `List(a, a)` despite `List(a)` is required

Comment: Is it better now? I spent a little too much time on it :)

Comment: Yes, it works now. `Iterator(null)` looks ugly indeed but the solution looks pretty simple. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it works with huge input too. The solution looks really good and I am accepting the answer (and will think how to get rid of this `Iterator(null)`).

Comment: Would it be easy to add  the number of repeated words and their indices ? For instance, `[aaabccb] => [(a, 0, 3), (c, 4, 2)]` Maybe I should ask a new question about it.

Comment: Position Would be easy, number of repeated words rather not, at least in this implementation i guess.

Comment: I've updated answer. I figured out some neat method to calculate what you have asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Need some time to grok it :) Not as easy as I thought ...

Comment: Ok... I've edited answer once again. In https://scalafiddle.io/sf/w5yozTA/15 I've added test for laziness that shows where pure functional implementation wins over imperative one, and why we should care. It was nice challenge 4 me. Have nice day @Michael :)

Comment: Oh, thank you for the effort. I will definitely have a look. I am glad you think it was a nice challenge :) Finally I have to solve it by myself :))

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with an Accumulator:

```
  case class Acc(word: String = "", count: Int = 0, index: Int = 0)

  def foo(in: Iterator[String]) =
    in.zipWithIndex
      .foldLeft(List(Acc())) { case (Acc(w, c, i) :: xs, (word: String, index)) =>
        if (word == w) // keep counting
          Acc(w, c + 1, i) :: xs
        else
          Acc(word, 1, index) :: Acc(w, c, i) :: xs
      }.filter(_.count > 1)
      .reverse

  val it = Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa")
```

This returns `List(Acc(aaa,2,0), Acc(cc,2,3), Acc(aaa,4,7))`

It also handles if the same word has another group with repeated words.

And you have the index of the occurrences as well as the count.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Would it work if the input is huge and the words do not fit in memory ?

Comment: As @Leo C explained `foldLeft` will take the size of the elements. But what you could do is stream your input and than run foo with a certain collection. (Like split the input stream)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses only the original iterator. No intermediate collections. So everything stays completely lazy and is suitable for very large input data.

```
def foo(in: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] =
  Iterator.unfold(in.buffered){ itr =>   // <--- Scala 2.13
    def loop :Option[String] =
      if (!itr.hasNext) None
      else {
        val str = itr.next()
        if (!itr.hasNext) None
        else if (itr.head == str) {
          while (itr.hasNext && itr.head == str) itr.next() //remove repeats
          Some(str)
        }
        else loop
      }
    loop.map(_ -> itr)
  }
```

testing:

```
val it = Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd")
foo(it) // Iterator("aaa", "cc")

//pseudo-infinite iterator
val piIt = Iterator.iterate(8)(_+1).map(_/3)  //2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5, etc.
foo(piIt.map(_.toString))                     //3,4,5,6, etc.
```

Comment: I've tested this foo method with my examples. Works as expected. Cannot create scalafiddle because it does not support scala 2.13 yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could traverse the collection using `foldLeft` with its accumulator being a Tuple of Map and String to keep track of the previous word for the conditional word counts, followed by a `collect`, as shown below:

```
def foo(in: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] =
  in.foldLeft((Map.empty[String, Int], "")){ case ((m, prev), word) =>
      val count = if (word == prev) m.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1 else 1
      (m + (word -> count), word)
    }._1.
    collect{ case (word, count) if count > 1 => word }.
    iterator

foo(Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd")).toList
// res1: List[String] =  List("aaa", "cc")
```

To capture also the repeated word counts and indexes, just index the collection and apply similar tactic for the conditional word count:

```
def bar(in: Iterator[String]): Map[(String, Int), Int] =
  in.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((Map.empty[(String, Int), Int], "", 0)){
      case ((m, pWord, pIdx), (word, idx)) =>
        val idx1 = if (word == pWord) idx min pIdx else idx
        val count = if (word == pWord) m.getOrElse((word, idx1), 0) + 1 else 1
        (m + ((word, idx1) -> count), word, idx1)
    }._1.
    filter{ case ((_, _), count) => count > 1 }

bar(Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd", "cc", "cc", "cc"))
// res2: Map[(String, Int), Int] = Map(("cc", 7) -> 3, ("cc", 3) -> 2, ("aaa", 0) -> 2)
```

---

UPDATE:

As per the revised requirement, to minimize memory usage, one approach would be to keep the Map to a minimal size by removing elements of count `1` (which would be the majority if few words are repeated) on-the-fly during the `foldLeft` traversal. Method `baz` below is a revised version of `bar`:

```
def baz(in: Iterator[String]): Map[(String, Int), Int] =
  (in ++ Iterator("")).zipWithIndex.
    foldLeft((Map.empty[(String, Int), Int], (("", 0), 0), 0)){
      case ((m, pElem, pIdx), (word, idx)) =>
        val sameWord = word == pElem._1._1
        val idx1 = if (sameWord) idx min pIdx else idx
        val count = if (sameWord) m.getOrElse((word, idx1), 0) + 1 else 1
        val elem = ((word, idx1), count)
        val newMap = m + ((word, idx1) -> count)
        if (sameWord) {
          (newMap, elem, idx1)
        } else
          if (pElem._2 == 1)
            (newMap - pElem._1, elem, idx1)
          else
            (newMap, elem, idx1)
    }._1.
    filter{ case ((word, _), _) => word != "" }

baz(Iterator("aaa", "aaa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "dd", "cc", "cc", "cc"))
// res3: Map[(String, Int), Int] = Map(("aaa", 0) -> 2, ("cc", 3) -> 2, ("cc", 7) -> 3)
```

Note that the dummy empty String appended to the input collection is to ensure that the last word gets properly processed as well.

Comment: Thanks. Would it work if the input file is huge and does not fit in memory ?

Comment: Probably not, unfortunately, as this solution involves using of a Map aggregating from the input (unless lots of the words are repeated in which case the Map might be relatively small).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added this limitation to the question.

Comment: To address the said limitation, you could minimize the size of the aggregation Map (which has `O(1)` lookup time) as shown in my expanded answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's some complex compare to another answers, but it use relatively small additional memory. And probably more fast.

```scala
def repeatedWordsIndex(in: Iterator[String]): java.util.Iterator[String] = {
  val initialCapacity = 4096
  val res = new java.util.ArrayList[String](initialCapacity) // or mutable.Buffer or mutable.Set, if you want Scala
  var prev: String = null
  var next: String = null
  var prevEquals = false
  while (in.hasNext) {
    next = in.next()
    if (next == prev) {
      if (!prevEquals) res.add(prev)
      prevEquals = true
    } else {
      prevEquals = false
    }
    prev = next
  }
  res.iterator // may be need to call distinct
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'd prefer "functional style" :)

Comment: tested this with my examples and works as expected. Here is scalafiddl: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/w5yozTA/6

Comment: i've added some stuff to scalafiddle to compare both solutions. It seams your code is  faster (But this is not valid benchmark, it's made just for curiosity, and proper benchmark needs to be done if you really care about it). https://scalafiddle.io/sf/w5yozTA/10