# How to remove repeated elements from an iterator?

Tags: string, list, scala, collections, functional-programming

This a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398665/iterator-of-repeated-words-in-a-file).
How would you write a function to filter out adjacent duplicates from a given iterator?

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = ???
remove("aaabccbbad".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString) // "abcbad"
```

P.S. The function should work when the whole input does not fit in the memory. That's why the function uses iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform the input iterator to an iterator of lists of duplicates and then just map every list to its head. In order to do it I would use two functions from my previous questions:

- function `splitDupes: Iterator[A] => (List[A], Iterator[A])` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148347/521070)) to split out a prefix of duplicates and return a pair of the prefix and the rest
- function `split: Iterator[A] => Iterator[List[A]]` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60030280/521070)) to transform a given iterator into an iterator of lists of duplicates using `splitDupes`.

Thanks a lot to [Kolmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098230/kolmar) for these suggestions. Using them I can implement `remove` like that:

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = split(it).flatMap(_.headOption)
```

See below implementations of `splitDupes` and `split` just for the reference:

```
def splitDupes[A](it: Iterator[A]): (List[A], Iterator[A]) = {
  if (it.isEmpty) {
    (Nil, Iterator.empty)
  } else {
    val head = it.next()
    val (dupes, rest) = it.span(_ == head)
    (head +: dupes.toList, rest)
  }
}

def split[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[List[A]] = {
  Iterator.iterate(splitDupes(it))(x => splitDupes(x._2)).map(_._1).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
"aaabccbbad"
    .map(ch => s"${ch}")
    .reduce((s1, s2) => if(s1.takeRight(1) == s2) s1 else s1 + s2)
```

This results in

> res0: String = abcbad

First for convenience I'm casting chars to strings. Then I'm comparing the last character of what I have already with consecutive characters and if they are different, I'm appending it.

More generally it could be like that:

```
stream.map(el => ListBuffer.empty.addOne(el))
    .reduce((lb1, lb2) => if(lb1.last == lb2.last) lb1 else lb1.addAll(lb2))
    .toList
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it work if all the input does not fit in the memory ?

Comment: I updated the question to mention the memory condition.

Comment: @Michael taking scala's stream laziness into account I'd say yes, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't see any streams. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Michael you're right, I didn't mention it. You can use this chain on `Stream` or `LazyList`, then consecutive elements will be evaluated lazily.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure that the stream solution works if the all the input does not fit in memory though. I should check it.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too low level. But this ensures that it will be only consuming elements as they are needed.

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] =
  new Iterator[A] {
    private[this] var current: Option[A] = None

    override def hasNext: Boolean =
      it.hasNext || (current ne None)

    override def next(): A = {
      @annotation.tailrec
      def loop(): A = (it.nextOption(), current) match {
        case (Some(a), Some(c)) if (a == c) =>
          loop()

        case (sa @ Some(a), Some(c)) =>
          current = sa
          c

        case (sa @ Some(a), None) =>
          current = sa
          loop()

        case (None, Some(c)) =>
          current = None
          c

        case (None, None) =>
          Iterator.empty[A].next()
      }

      loop()
    }
  }
```

---

More or less the same as above, but using `unfold` instead.

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = {
  type State = (Option[A], Option[A]) // value -> current

  def process(state: State): Option[State] = state match {
    case (Some(a), sc @ Some(c)) if (a == c) =>
      Some(None -> sc)

    case (sa @ Some(a), sc @ Some(c)) =>
      Some(sc -> sa)

    case (sa @ Some(a), None) =>
      Some(None -> sa)

    case (None, sc @ Some(c)) =>
      Some(sc -> None)

    case (None, None) =>
      None
  }

  Iterator.unfold(it.nextOption() -> Option.empty[A]) { state =>
    process(state).map {
      case (value, current) =>
        (value -> (it.nextOption() -> current))
    }
  } collect {
    case Some(a) => a
  }
}
```

---

*(they could be made more efficient using `null` instead of **Option**, but it requires special handling of primitives)*

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid implementing `hasNext` and `next` though.

Comment: @Michael I would suggest you to take a look to **Streaming** libraries instead. like `fs2` & `AkkaStreams`.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution w/o 3d-party libraries.

Comment: @Michael you are asking for too many things. An efficient lazy stream with high level combinator is not easy to implement, for that reason there exist robust libraries providing that.

Comment: @Michael I just edited my question with a somewhat more highlevel alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did not know about `unfold`.

Comment: I've added my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think its easier with tail recursion:

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = {
  def removeLoop(result: Iterator[A], remaining: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = {
    if(remaining.isEmpty) {
      result
    } else {
      val e = remaining.next();
      removeLoop(result ++ Iterator(e), remaining.dropWhile(a => a == e))
    }  
  }

  removeLoop(Iterator.empty[A], it)
}

remove("aaabccbbad".iterator).toList.map(_.toString).mkString // "abcbad"
```

---

Edit: As per the comment, the above implementation is not lazy.

A possible lazy implementation will look something like this:

```
def remove[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
  var lastElement: A = _

  def hasNext: Boolean = it.hasNext

  def next(): A = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def nextLoop(lastElement: A, it: Iterator[A]): A = {
      val temp = it.next
      if(lastElement == temp)
        nextLoop(lastElement, it)
      else
        temp
    }
    lastElement = nextLoop(lastElement, it)
    lastElement
  }
}

remove("aaabccbbad".iterator).take(2).foreach(print) // "ab"
remove("aaabccbbad".iterator).foreach(print) // "abcbad"
```

Comment: I am afraid it won't be lazy.

Comment: I think the solution is lazy. The iterator is not converted into any other (non-lazy) collection, so it will not load everything in memory at once. All the operations used are from iterator class itself (which mostly generates new iterators) and next() makes an element available. 
I have not tested it though. Do you have any particular reason to think it will not be lazy?

Comment: I tried something like that and it was not lazy. I will check this solution  ...

Comment: I've added `println(e)` after `val e = remaining.next();`. When I run `remove("aaabccbbad".iterator)` it prints all characters of "abcbad". That's _not_ what I call "lazy". Am I missing something ?

Comment: You are right. The implementation was not lazy. I have put in one more solution to make it lazy.

Comment: Thanks. Looks lazy indeed. However I still prefer my solution :))